# Convert Arctangent Equality

Tags: trigonometry

Note that $\arctan(57)=-4 \cdot \arctan(1)+3 \cdot \arctan(2)+\arctan(5)$. How can I obtain $\arctan(\frac{1}{57})=−2\cdot \arctan(1)+3 \cdot \arctan(\frac{1}{2})+\arctan(\frac{1}{5})$ from the above equality?

Moreover, given $\arctan(47)=4 \cdot \arctan(1)+\arctan(2)-\arctan(4)-\arctan(5)$, how can I convert it into another equality involving $\arctan(\frac{1}{47})$?

Comment: $\arctan (1/x)=\pi/2-\arctan x$ for $x>0$.

Comment: ...and therefore $\arctan(\frac{1}{47})=2\arctan(1)-\arctan(47)$.